# AngularJS datepicker not updating the model

Tags: angularjs, model, datepicker

Am trying to use the angular JS datepicker directive, the model is not getting updated.

the text box is getting updated, however, when i click the button next to the text box, the console just shows "" which i set it before.

You can download the example code at https://github.com/g00fy-/angular-datepicker

Can any help here pls?

-Vasu

Comment: Add plnkr with your code.

Comment: I have made a plnkr here , http://plnkr.co/edit/hOpIgY4iBoVve5Xlfaco?p=preview